# how do i override jquery show() event?

Tags: jquery

i am trying to override the show behaviour a library element and replace it with a slideDown. Is it possible to override or modify pre-existing function for single selector with jQuery?

something like

```
$(".library-class").onShow(function (event){
  $(event.target).slideDown();
});
```

i've tried the on() function. this does not show the alert

```
$('.library-class').on("show", function(event) {
    alert("working!");
});
```

This overrides show() for all selectors, but not for a single selector:

```
jQuery.fn.show = function() {
// Your custom code
```

}

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override jquery's show() and hide() functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966314/how-to-override-jquerys-show-and-hide-functions)

Comment: the reference doesn't resolve my question. related, but not a duplicate. iave mofidied to the question to show why this reference does not work for a single selector.

Comment: May I know what exactly/specifically/practically you are trying to achieve? Because if you want to `slideDown` to show, you can directly use it with the combination of `slideUp` to hide, you don't need to override show method

Comment: Thank you for reply: I want to override an existing third party show() function to replace it with a slideDown() for a single selector only.

Comment: Also I want to clarify why $("selector").on("show"...) does not work...?

Comment: Once check my example I posted below, hope that will solve your problems.

Comment: thank  you that does work to intercept the on("show") event, but i am unable to override the show action with slide. event.preventDefault has no effect. Is that possible using your example as a basis.

Comment: i have tried following code which shows the slide effect, but it corrupts the dimensions of the div on completion.  
$('.show').on('show', function(event) {
   alert(event.target.nodeName);
   event.preventDefault();
   $(event.target).slideDown();
 });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188883/discussion-between-rahul-meshram-and-laurence-fass).

Answer (score 0):

Show, Hide, Toggle all events are working in this example.

```js
(function($) {
  $.each(['show', 'hide'], function(i, ev) {
    var el = $.fn[ev];
    $.fn[ev] = function() {
      this.trigger(ev);
      return el.apply(this, arguments);
    };
  });
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#foo').on('show', function() {
    console.log('#foo is now visible');
  });

  $('#foo').on('hide', function() {
    console.log('#foo is hidden');
  });
  $("#togle").on("click", function() {
    $("#foo").toggle();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">this is test the thunder</div>
<input type="button" id="togle" value="Toggle" />
```

Comment: Happy to Help.  If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Rahul for your simple elegant answer.

```js
(function($) {
  $.each(['show', 'hide'], function(i, ev) {
    var el = $.fn[ev];
    $.fn[ev] = function() {
      this.trigger(ev);
      return el.apply(this, arguments);
    };
  });
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#foo').on('show', function() {
    console.log('#foo is now visible');
  });

  $('#foo').on('hide', function() {
    console.log('#foo is hidden');
  });
  $("#togle").on("click", function() {
    $("#foo").toggle();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">this is test the thunder</div>
<input type="button" id="togle" value="Toggle" />
```