# overwrite the show method in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

am editing a web app (not my code) , and has alot of modals show up when some message or notification come
 so i want to add a sound for that modal

the problem that this modal is in all over the app , and alot of jquery .show methods i should track and add that sound

```
 $('#ajax_alert').show();
```

i tried to listen to a change, like changing in css attributes but didn't work

```
$('#ajax_alert').on("change",function(){
//make sound
})
```

how can i overwrite the show method ? i can trigger the sound inside it by checking if triggered id is ajax_alert, play that sound !

Comment: Overriding an existing jQuery method isn't a great idea, and besides how would you know that the target element is a modal?. Depending on the modal library you're using there may be events you can listen for when a modal is opened which you can use to run the code you require.

Comment: Agreed. Unfortunately, I think the fact it's using `.show()` might mean this is not one of the common modal libraries out there.

Comment: @Mohamad Alasly - There might be certain class you are adding to the `active modal` only. You can look for existence of this class and get the active modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the comments that it's probably not the best idea and it seems a bit hacky, but it *can* be done.

So what the JQuery `.show()` method does is just change an element's CSS to `display: block;` right? So you can overwrite the `.show` method, but tell it to keep doing that and then also add some additional functionality:

```js
jQuery.fn.show = function() {
   this.css('display', 'block');
   setTimeout(() => alert('My very own added functionality'), 0); // Newly added functionality
   return this;
};

$('a').click(function() {
   $('div').show()
})
```

```css
div {margin-top: 20px; background-color: blue; height: 60px; width: 60px; display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Click to show div</a>
<div></div>
```

Working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Ludolfyn/Laqcpe3f/):